# Strange new users with Chinese/Korean usernames

Tags: discussion, specific-user, new-users, display-names

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?page=399&tab=newusers), we can see many 1-rep users with Chinese or Korean usernames. Their profile photos are their usernames themselves. I am a Chinese native speaker, I can see their usernames do not seem to be real names.

Perhaps there are robots creating new profiles automatically? Do we need to do something about this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Interesting. Could it be promotion for a product or something like this? Some time ago we had many users with names like "Car insurance in Arizona" that were created for promotion.

Comment: A good chunk of English usernames are obviously not real names but just account handles. I'm also a Mandarin native speaker, and as far as I can tell, the proportion of obviously-fake Chinese usernames are not particularly higher in comparison (if anything, it actually seems considerably lower). Neither do I see any sign of guerrilla marketing, or for that matter, social/cultural advocates.

Comment: Having said that, it does seem like a sudden influx of new users with Chinese handles. Whether or not it is alarming is hard to say. Chinese tech companies do have a bad reputation. On the other hand, the shear number of existing Chinese college students can easily make the bump of several thousands new users nothing out of the ordinary. It could be that somewhere in China locally "on a small scale" that people who previously were unaware are recently informed of StackExchange (or maybe even students are instructed to register).

Comment: I agree.  Maybe some Chinese college student noticed that this was a useful site, and publicized that fact, so lots of others have joined.  I say, do nothing special for these users.  We may ask, **why** did that first one find this site useful ... we can hope it was some reason other than: They will do your homework for you.

Comment: Definitely need to keep an eye on this!

Comment: Thank you for noticing. And thanks also to @Lee and the other Chinese speaking users. If you do notice something odd going on, please flag it for moderator attention. Preferably with a custom flag to explain the situation better, if possible.

Comment: There is nothing suspicious. The images of those users seems to be generated by google. Google generate this sort of icons for all its users but for user with western first name, it is pretty useless (e.g. mine is a single 'A'). My wild guess is for user with non-western first name, this sort of icons is distinct enough and SE use that instead of those from gravatar...

Comment: @achillehui ah!  I didn’t even connect this with the auto generated google initials.  I thought someone said the timing was suspicious, though.  Maybe just an optical illusion?

Comment: The link you offered has been [bumped to here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?page=401&tab=newusers) (401 versus 399, it's incremented a couple of pages). --- I checked a few accounts and they do have Google logins. Since we offer "Sign in with Google" it's not unusual, nor are the accounts over there suspicious or SPAMmy. --- We appreciate your mentioning this nonetheless.

Comment: It's odd that the new users are via Google logins. Use of Google in China is officially blocked, and is inconvenient, at best. So, most people in China use Baidu, rather than Google.

Comment: Please notice that this is not only about Chinese users. There are also Korean, Arabic and many other users of this type.

Comment: @bubba I’ve heard of that Gmail is unblocked in mainland China recently.

Comment: I've recommend this site to my classmates for several times. I'm not sure if they joined in and talked about this to any others.

Comment: @Szeto No. It have not been unbanned in China.

Comment: I saw that not only MSE, but also MO and SO have this problem.

Comment: @KemonoChen From the past 10 pages, I found on average 1 username per page (36 users) using Chinese/Korean/Japanese/Asian characters, or sometimes none. Since everyone ([100 million people](https://www.zdnet.com/article/vpns-can-still-be-used-in-china-despite-march-31-ban/)) using a VPN in China is aware of outside sites, and there are [4.2 billion people](https://www.internetworldstats.com/stats.htm) using the Internet worldwide, there isn't a significant difference between Math SE and other sites.

Comment: Please can you give an example to search? I've been typing random Chinese and Korean letters into my keyboard and its either nothing or genuine people.

Comment: @user10176969 Example:"龙泽洲". Since the page I have given is changing, you can see the last page (427 now) instead of the page I have given.

Comment: It'd probably be good to make a screen shot, and include it in the question, since the links keep becoming stale.

Comment: I strongly agree with @NateEldredge, but for some reason I can't post the screenshot, could someone help me make a screenshot?

Comment: @KemonoChen: Is this the sort of thing you mean? https://imgur.com/a/qTKSV4e

Comment: @NateEldredge Exactly what I mean. Thank you and I will add the link in my post.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Regarding your "sudden influx" comment: The number of new users with Chinese or Korean or Arabic handles seems to be much much smaller than the number of new users with Latin alphabet handles.  Is there some other data you are looking at?

Comment: @Kimball Yes, that's a good point. The comparison of flux (of e.g. fall semester boost) I personally was considering is not between [Chinese or Korean or Arabic] vs. [Latin alphabet], but was between [Chinese or Korean in 2017 or prior] vs. [Chinese or Korean after summer of 2018]. I also need to reiterate my stance that there's most likely nothing fishy going on until proven otherwise.